# facebook comments plugin for wordpress loading very slow

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I am working on a website, and installed Wordpress with the SEO Facebook comments plugin. After installing this plugin the page loads very slowly;

http://www.weddingpages.nl/blog/2013/bruidsbeurzen/

I checked the Apache logfiles and see that after the request for this page the actual page starts loading about 5 seconds later.
I spend hours checking settings and googled for solutions but found nothing. Is there anybody who can help me with this ?